# Extract height from every dendrogram node using dendrapply

Tags: r, apply, dendrogram, dendextend

Probably very simple,

I have a `dendrogram`:

```
set.seed(1)
my_mat <- matrix(rnorm(100),nrow=10,ncol=10)
my_dend <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(my_mat)))
```

and I want to use `dendrapply` to extract the `height` `attribute` from every `node` in `my_dend`, since it traverses the `dendrogram` in `pre-order`.

Trying `dendrapply`'s [example](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/dendrapply.html) on `my_dend`:

```
dendrapply(my_dend, function(n) utils::str(attributes(n)))
```

It doesn't return a value but prints the information I need in `pre-order`. I thought that just getting the `height` `attribute` returned is as simple as:

```
dendrapply(my_dend, function(n) attr(n,"height"))
```

but obviously I'm wrong.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
sapply(hclust(dist(my_mat)), '[')$height
#[1] 2.195193 2.661372 2.837259 2.890944 3.745600 4.098533 4.177088 5.514541 6.496675
#and order
sapply(hclust(dist(my_mat)), '[')$order
# [1]  4  1 10  8  9  2  5  7  3  6
```

There's also `dendextend_get_branches_heights` in library `dendextend`

```
dendextend_get_branches_heights(my_dend)
#[1] 2.195193 2.661372 2.837259 2.890944 3.745600 4.098533 4.177088 5.514541 6.496675
```

Comment: I don't think so. dendrapply prints Heights in pre-order, which is what I'm interested in

Comment: I updated my question to specify that I'm interested in pre-order, which is how dendrapply seems to be traversing, unlike looping over the hclust object or using dendextend

Answer (score 1):

To get the height of all nodes in your dendrogram,  you can use the function `get_nodes_attr` from the dendextend package.

```
library(dendextend)
get_nodes_attr(my_dend, "height")

 [1] 6.496675 0.000000 5.514541 3.745600 2.195193 0.000000 0.000000 2.890944
 [9] 0.000000 0.000000 4.177088 2.837259 0.000000 0.000000 4.098533 0.000000
[17] 2.661372 0.000000 0.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

This is by far from elegant but works:

save the output of

```
dendrapply(my_dend, function(n) utils::str(attributes(n)))
```

to a file, and edit that file:

```
  out.fn <- "dendrogram.output"
  capture.output(dendrapply(my_dend, function(n) utils::str(attributes(n))),file=out.fn)
  system(paste0("sed -i '/List of/d' ",out.fn))
  system(paste0("sed -i '/\\[\\[/d' ",out.fn))
  system(paste0("sed -i '/NULL/d' ",out.fn))
  system(paste0("sed -i '/^$/d' ",out.fn))
  system(paste0("sed -i '/class/d' ",out.fn))
  system(paste0("sed -i '/midpoint/d' ",out.fn))
  system(paste0("sed -i '/leaf/d' ",out.fn))
  system(paste0("sed -i '/label/d' ",out.fn))
  system(paste0("sed -i '/members/d' ",out.fn))
  system(paste0("sed -i 's/ \\$ //g' ",out.fn))
  system(paste0("perl -i -pe 's/height\\s+:\\s+num\\s+//g' ",out.fn))

  my_dend.df <- dplyr::filter(read.table(out.fn,header=F,sep=",",stringsAsFactors=F,col.names="depth"),depth != 0)

> my_dend.df
  depth
1  6.50
2  5.51
3  3.75
4  2.20
5  2.89
6  4.18
7  2.84
8  4.10
9  2.66
```